# How to make Angular Material Card Title one liner?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am unable to force `mat-card-title` to stay in one line and cut off the extra text.

I have tried the css class below (text-oneline).

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title class="text-oneline">Heeeeeellllllloooo</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>World!</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image [src]="icon_url" alt="App Icon">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>Hello</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

```css
.text-oneline {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Right now, the text is longer than the card. I would like the text to stop and not overflow the card.
I want the text to fill all available space but not go over the width of the mat-card.

Example: https://angular-mat-card-example-4cb2wk.stackblitz.io

Solution:

The code by לבני מלכה works great, but only after window.resize is triggered. The simples solution I found was editing `mat-card-header`.

```css
mat-card-header {
  display: flow-root;
}
```

Comment: I like your own solution best. You should add it as an answer! I had to sift through the answers and comments before I realized what you were doing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you card in `div` and set elementRef to div as `#card`

Then set width to `header` as the card's width `[style.width.px]="width - 50"`

Set the width param on resize `(window:resize)="width=card.getBoundingClientRect().width"`

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-c9diuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div #card (window:resize)="width=card.getBoundingClientRect().width">
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title class="text-oneline" [style.width.px]="width - 50">Heeeeeellllllloooo</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>World!</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image [src]="icon_url" alt="App Icon">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>Hello</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-oneline {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I want to keep my mat-card responsive.

Comment: so what you problem? do you want to set `ellipsis` only in small device?

Comment: Maybe I did not ask the questions right. I want the text to fill all available space but not go over the width of the mat-card.

Comment: you can use `mat-card{
 word-break: break-word;

}
`

Comment: I attached a stackblitz to my original question. `word-break` did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I can offer two solutions one of which I don't really want to give, but it's a solution.

The solution I recommend you to use is to remove the wrapping `<mat-card-header>`

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title class="text-oneline">Heeeeeellllllloooo</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-subtitle>World!</mat-card-subtitle>
  <img mat-card-image [src]="icon_url" alt="App Icon">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>Hello</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

This will change the layout a little bit, but you can solve this by adding your own css classes or wrap it with your own div, just don't use `<mat-card-header>` because it does something that's not easy to circumvent, but not impossible like you'll see in my second, not so recommended, solution.

In this second solution you move the `.text-online` class onto the `<mat-card-header>` like so:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header class="text-oneline">
    <mat-card-title >Heeeeeellllllloooo</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>World!</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image [src]="icon_url" alt="App Icon">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>Hello</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

and your css changes to:

```
.text-oneline ::ng-deep * {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**I do NOT recommend you use this second solution!**

Using ::ng-deep is considered very bad practive because it's deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore, but as of today Angular has not provided an alternative. [More info](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: Your first solution gave me the idea to simply change `mat-card-header`. I think `display: flow-root;` is the simplest solution.

Comment: first solution is much better option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for this use CSS word-break: break-all 
refer following code block

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title  style="word-break: break-all">Heeeeeellllllloooo</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>World!</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image [src]="icon_url" alt="App Icon">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>Hello</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: refer his last comment "Maybe I did not ask the questions right. I want the text to fill all available space but not go over the width of the mat-card"

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Giovani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6582779/giovani-vercauteren)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55633678/8998260) and [hennyKo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9309705/hennyko)'s comment:

You don't have to remove `<mat-card-header>` tag. Just add below css:

```
mat-card-header {
    display: flow-root;
}
```

And to make the title one liner:

```
.text-oneline {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```